# Conditional distribution of the modulus of the output of AWGN channel given the  modulus of the input

Tags: st.statistics, pr.probability

Hi everyone,

I will be too happy if anybody help me find a solution for the following problem.
In fact, I have a big problem that I could not solve it for weeks.

Assume that we have we have two independent zero mean Gaussian random variables, $X$ and $Z$ and we define the new random variable $Y$ as $Y=X+Z$. I define the sign and the magnitude of this three random variables as $X_s$, $Y_s$ and $Z_s \in \{+1,-1\}$, $X_M$, $Y_M$ and $Z_M \in R^+$, respectively. 
It is clear that the pairs $X_s$ and $X_M$ are independent, this is the same for $Y_s$ and $Y_M$, $Y_s$ and $Y_M$.

My problem is how to find the conditional distribution $f(y_M|x_M)=?$.

I have a solution for this but I could not convince myself that my answer is true.
We have, 
$$f(y_M|x_M)= f(y_M|x_M,x_s=+1)f(x_s=+1|x_M)+ f(y_M|x_M,x_s=-1)f(x_s=-1|x_M)$$
$$=f(y_m|x_M,x_s=+1)f(x_s=+1)+ f(y_M|x_M,x_s=-1)f(x_s=-1)$$
$$=0.5*(f(y_M|x_M,x_s=+1)+ f(y_M|x_M,x_s=-1))$$
then, since both $f(y_M|x_M,x_s=+1)$ and $f(y_M|x_M,x_s=-1)$ have the same distribution, i.e., "Folded normal distribution" then from above equation $f(y_M|x_M)$ follows "Folded normal distribution".

If it is correct it means that $f(y_M|x_M)= f(y_M|x_M,x_s)$ that implies $X_s$ and $Y_M$ condition on $X_M$ are independent!!!!!!!!!!!

But from  $y_M = \lvert x+z \rvert$, $Y_M$ depends on both $X_M$ and $X_s$ !!!!
I am really confused and I will be too grateful if anybody help me solve the problem.
Thanks a lot in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $Y_M$ is independent of $X_s$ - it doesn't matter whether or not you condition on $X_M$.
You essentially give the answer yourself - conditioning on $X_M$, you get that $Y |  X_M$ is a symmetric r.v., with $f(Y|X_M) = \frac{1}{2\sigma_Z}[\varphi(\frac{Y-X_M}{\sigma_z})+\varphi(\frac{Y+X_M}{\sigma_z})]$ where $\varphi$ is the standard normal density. Therefore, summing on $Y=\pm Y_M$ you get $f(Y_M|X_M) = \frac{1}{\sigma_Z}[\varphi(\frac{Y_M-X_M}{\sigma_z})+\varphi(\frac{Y_M+X_M}{\sigma_z})]$ (for any $Y_M \geq 0$) which is equal to $f(Y_M|X_M,X_s)$. It is true that $Y=X+Z$ depends on $X_s$ but you can write $f(Y | X_s=1) = f(-Y | X_s=-1)$ and when you take the absolute value $Y_M = |Y|$ becomes independent of $X_s$.

Comment: @ OrZuk, Thanks a lot for your answer.

Comment: @ OrZuk, again thanks for your answer, but I did not tour 4th sentence, summing on $Y=\pm Y_M$ ..., I will be too happy if you explain me in more details?

Comment: I meant that to get a particular value of $Y_M$ (which is non-negative), $Y$ can be either $Y_M$ or $-Y_M$. Therefore, to get the
probability (actually density) of $Y_M$ attending a certain value, you should sum the density of $Y$ attaining this value or it's minus.